# problemaas con CSS en ios

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

Desarrollé una página con html5 y css que se muestra bien en Android, Chrome y Firefox (Windows) y simuladores de iphone online (en windows) pero cuando lo testeo en un iPhone o MacBook desconfigura los párrafos, no respetando el interlineado por defecto. Aquí muestro lo que sucede:
en ANDROID:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En iPhone:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el sgte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>iphone test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>

    <section class="iphone-section">
        <h2>Generá <span class="bold">tu popia</span> energía solar fotovoltaica</h2>
        <div class="caja-parent">
            <div class="caja-child">
                <?php require 'multimedia/24-7.svg'; ?>
                <p class="">Funcionamiento permanente</p>
            </div>

            <div class="caja-child">
                <?php require 'multimedia/currency.svg'; ?>
                <p class="">Garantía de ahorro energético</p>
            </div>

            <div class="caja-child">
                <?php require 'multimedia/sun.svg'; ?>
                <p class="">Fuente de energía inagotable</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center-div">
            <a href="#" class="btn-scroll ">Cotizar ahora</a>
        </div>
        <footer class="flex flex-dir-row gap-default flex-jc-spbetween">
            <div class="col-50">
                <div class="landscape-footer">
                    <p><a href="#" class="">Novedades</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="">Contacto</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="inline footer-rrss" style="margin-top: 1em;">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-youtube"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dev" class="col-50" style="text-align: right;">
                <p>BRAND®</p>
                <p class="tiny"> Desarrollado por :)</a></p>

            </div>
        </footer>
    </section>

    <?php require 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Y el CSS:

```
section.iphone-section {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    section.iphone-section h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 36px;
    }


    .caja-parent {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        padding: 0 0.7em;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 10px;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .caja-child {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        min-height: 120px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .caja-child svg {
        max-height: 75px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .caja-child svg {
            max-height: 50px;
        }
    }
```

He intentado editando CSS: usando `box-sizing` y quitándolo, declarando el `line-height` pero de ninguna manera resulta.
Alguna idea de qué puede estar faltando en el código que no haya tenido en cuenta?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema:

Posiblemente sea porque en resoluciones más pequeñas, tus contenedores **siguen alineados en filas**. Lo mejor sería que esos contenedores estén alineados en columnas cuando estemos en resoluciones más pequeñas.

#### Solución:

Prueba con lo siguiente, aquí indico que si superamos el ancho de `450px`, los contenedores que son encerrados por su contenedor padre `caja-parent` se alinearán en columnas y serán justificadas al centro, y cada contenedor hijo llamado `caja-child` ocupará todo el ancho de la pantalla para que esté perfectamente centrado:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .caja-parent {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .caja-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

#### Ejemplo:

```css
section.iphone-section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

section.iphone-section h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}


.caja-parent {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.caja-child {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  min-height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.caja-child svg {
  max-height: 75px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .caja-child svg {
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .caja-parent {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .caja-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="iphone-section">
  <h2>Generá <span class="bold">tu popia</span> energía solar fotovoltaica</h2>
  <div class="caja-parent">
    <div class="caja-child">
      <?php require 'multimedia/24-7.svg'; ?>
      <p class="">Funcionamiento permanente</p>
    </div>

    <div class="caja-child">
      <?php require 'multimedia/currency.svg'; ?>
      <p class="">Garantía de ahorro energético</p>
    </div>

    <div class="caja-child">
      <?php require 'multimedia/sun.svg'; ?>
      <p class="">Fuente de energía inagotable</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-div">
    <a href="#" class="btn-scroll ">Cotizar ahora</a>
  </div>
  <footer class="flex flex-dir-row gap-default flex-jc-spbetween">
    <div class="col-50">
      <div class="landscape-footer">
        <p><a href="#" class="">Novedades</a></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="">Contacto</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="inline footer-rrss" style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-youtube"></i></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i class="bi bi-linkedin"></i></a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dev" class="col-50" style="text-align: right;">
      <p>BRAND®</p>
      <p class="tiny"> Desarrollado por :)</a></p>

  </div>
</footer>
</section>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/qBQqWav).

Comment: Incluso definiendo un ancho y/o alto del contenedor padre el error en la vista persiste. He estado buscando documentación y en foros pero el problema en la visualización en dispositivos de apple se repite; incluso hasta ni siquiera muestra el contenido de texto en algunos

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es identificar mediante **UserAgent**; los datos del navegador, la versión y el sistema operativo en que te encuentras para de este modo poder ajustar el contenido a las "peculiaridades" de cada uno de ellos, pues cierto es que en algunas ocasiones se arrastran estilos de sistema difíciles de identificar. Una vez hecha esta identificación mediante estas funciones puedes solucionar el problema jugando con las propiedades **css** o de cualquier otro tipo para cada uno de ellos.

Mediante el uso de expresiones regulares se puede obtener el navegador y la versión con **javascript** del siguiente modo:

```js
var getBrowserInfo = function() {
    var navegador= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    Nave= navegador.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(Nave[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(navegador) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(Nave[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= navegador.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    Nave= Nave[2]? [Nave[1], Nave[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= navegador.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) Nave.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return Nave.join(' ');
};

console.log(getBrowserInfo());
```

Al ejecutar el código el resultado esperado se ve en la consola del navegador en que lo estés ejecutando.